# Measure divergence in Particle Swarm Optimization

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, optimization

I'd like to monitor divergence/diversity in my swarm during the particle swarm optimization algorithm to measure when the swarm search space is converging.

This would be used as one metric to be recorded during the run and potentially to terminate the PSO process when not much further progress is to be expected.

Is there a common metric for measuring PSO swarm divergence?